# How to read text from image in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to make mobile web app. The purpose of this app is that it will read text from jpg image and save that text in mobile phone. Is there any way to read text and numbers from image or photo(contains all text and numbers no complex shapes or something) using HTML5?

Comment: Maybe you should look up what the letters H T M L stand for.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that HTML5 contains necessary means for OCR or image processing. There are however native and java libraries suitable for this task.  But in general OCR and image processing are pretty advanced areas, and you will need a lot of knowledge to implement this.

Here is opensource java library which can be used ( and actually used ) for OCR in phone:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Comment: Can this be used in JavaScript? I want to use front end technologies JavaScript, jQuery, HTML5, CSS3 etc.

Comment: And I want a purple unicorn! This is a very complicated task, and of course you can find good PHP, Java, C# scripts for this. But frontend technologies? I don't think so.

Comment: Well, it can be done with javascript on mobile web browser -  but it does not mean that it should be done.

Comment: Somebody may sit down and write that script in javascript, but that will kill average PC. So best solution is server-side.

Comment: If someone can write [javascript to identify cats in images](http://harthur.github.io/kittydar/), there's bound to someone who can write `javascript` to identify text... :)

Comment: Identify cat in image ( with Haar cascade? ) is much easier  that to locate text,  and separate  4 from A and 2 from 5.  This is definitely possible to write in javascript,   but for now execution times will be prohibitive

Answer (score 0):

The libraries which uses simple  Euclidean Distance comparisons can be helpful for this.See that [here](http://www.heatonresearch.com/fun/ocr)

Comment: Trus me,  cluster matching with euclidian distance provides low recognition rates. You have to go for mahalanobis or maybe batthaharia distances.